# Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore')

Tags: android

Hello from some days I am trying to run android app. Here is the error being genrated,

```
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] ------------------------------
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] Android Launch!
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] Performing test123.com.pk.Test123Activity activity launch
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'droidX' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-12-26 20:48:21 - Test123] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'droidX'
[2011-12-26 20:48:34 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2011-12-26 20:48:34 - Test123] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-12-26 20:48:34 - Test123] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

It does not display anything on the screen except Android written. Please help me out. I have been trying it for days.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin access on your system? I saw this happening if your login doesn't have admin rights.

Comment: Yes I have the admin rights. Its an admin account in Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Complete reinstallation of SDK helped me. Maybe, also you did not wait enough to run an emulator. Provide us with logcat, please. Try to find what is happening there. If there are cycles of messages then it is not good. But if everything goes sequentially then you should wait more.